# Should 0.0.0.0 be accepted as answer to IP/netmask?

Tags: networking, user-interface, ip

For a product system that has prompts to configure the IP/netmask, should 0.0.0.0 etc be accepted when user enter them and throw an error immediately? Or should the system wait until the input is commited and return the error from underlying network adapter?

Prompts like this:

`Please enter the IP:`

`Please enter the netmask:`

(when user hit enter, both are commited and error is return, if any)

The argument for immediate rejection is that 0.0.0.0 is so obvious as invalid value. A system should be smart enough to detect that and prevent it from entering.

The argument for later rejection during commit is that there can be various invalid input and it's hard for the IP type system to catch. 1.1.1.1, 1.11.111.111 are invalid as well.
(well theoretically yes but practically not..)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last paragraph.  Detecting an invalid netmask is very easy (logically, just convert to binary, and ensure a contiguous sequence of msb-aligned 1s).  Incidentally, are you sure 0.0.0.0 is an invalid netmask?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, what you're saying is about netmask that I would agree. But how about IP addr?

Comment: How are you defining an invalid IP?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth， that's something I'm not sure hence the argument. Are you saying that 0.0.0.0 can be an valid IP? Or in general..

Comment: I think there are very few IP addresses that cannot be used; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#Reserved_IPv4_addresses.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address. It has exactly one use: as a pseudo-argument when binding. It is the value of INADDR_ANY. A user would never have a reason to enter this value. And the reference for TCP/IP is the RFCs, not secondary sources.

Comment: @Figo I would catch it in the UI. Why do you say 1.1.1.1, 1.11.111.111 are invalid?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You implied it: "there are very few IP addresses that cannot be used".

Comment: @EJP: Ah, misinterpreted then!  That quote was aimed at the OP's claim that 1.11.111.111 etc. are invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most systems handle this by having a list of 'martian' address ranges and invalidating things against that list.  Whether that's part of the UI or backend validation is highly dependent on your system.  If it's a networking system where people will by entering addresses and prefixes frequently, it's better to have that as a foreground capability.

BTW, rather than entering netmasks, modern systems now allow you to enter the number of significant bits, using CIDR's '/' notation for the number of significant bits.